# The complexity for bin packing variations

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, bin-packing

In the traditional bin-packing problem, the goal is to minimize the number of bins. If we define the cost for a bin as the maximum size of the objects allocated to that bin, and the objective is to minimize the total cost for a packing solution, which is the sum of the cost for all bins (the cost for an empty bin is thus zero), is there any name for this problem? Is it still NP-hard? If it is, how can we prove it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know a name for this problem.  To prove NP-hardness, you have to show how any instance of some known-to-be-NP-hard problem can be converted (in poly-time) to an instance of this problem so that the answer to the new problem tells you the answer to the original problem.  Hint: Try a reduction from "the easiest hard problem" ;)

Comment: Thank you, j_random_hacker, for the suggestion. I was trying to reduce from the regular bin-packing problem and not succeeded...The challenge here is that the cost of  a bin is only the size of the object with the largest one. Some more hints perhaps?  ;-)

Comment: Next hint: Can you add a few items of (somewhat carefully) chosen weight to force at least a certain number of bins, of known cost, to be required?

Comment: Actually it should also be possible to reduce from regular bin packing, using a very similar strategy.  Big hint: Think about what happens if you increase the size of the bins by some "large enough" amount, and also add some items of this size.

Comment: Thank you, j_random_hacker. Let me think about it first ...

Comment: j_random_hacker, here it is: So let the original bin size to be C, we can increase the bin size to be 2C+1. Then we can add k new objects with size of C+1 such that each bin can only hold at most one such new object. We try k from 1 to M, where M is the largest possible bin number. If the optimal solution can be found with each bin containing at least one "big" object, it is also the optimal solution for the original bin packing problem. Am I right?

Comment: Thank you so much, j_random_hacker! You are a genius!

Comment: You've basically got it, well done :)  One nitpick: Both of these problems are formally decision problems, that is, the k to use is provided as part of the problem instance, and the answer is always just "YES" (it can be done with at most k bins) or "NO" (it can't).  In practice you're generally looking to minimise k so you would do what you suggest (or binary search), but for the reduction you need to say under what conditions the answer to the original problem should be "YES" or "NO", based on the "YES" or "NO" answer to the reduced problem.